# Find out actual URL pattern match when servlet is mapped on multiple URL patterns

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've a list of links:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="enquire">Enquire<a></li>
</ul>
```

And the following servlet:

```
@WebServlet( urlPatterns={"/index","/contactus","/services","/enquire"})
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws            ServletException, IOException {


   //Index URL mapping should be checked here like

   if(request.getRequestURL().equals("/index"))
   {
       response.sendredirtect("index.jsp")
   }

   //Url for contact  us should be checked here


   if(request.getRequestURL().equals("/contactus"))
   {
       response.sendredirtect("contactus.jsp")
   }

   //same for all the above url requests
```

}

As the `getRequestURL()` method is a `StringBuffer`, it can not be checked for equality with the String `"/"`.

How can I achieve this anyway?

Comment: Rather than trying to map multiple urls to the same servlet, use a url rewriting engine like Tucket URL Rewrite filter.  Also, you wouldn't make a controller just to call `response.sendRedirect`...please explain your actual goal here rather than asking how to fix a broken solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a `toString()` on the `StringBuffer` to get a `String` out of it? It's maybe time to learn some basic Java before diving into Java EE and such.

You could also just lookup the [`HttpServletRequest` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to figure which methods are all available to obtain information from the request. You'll have noticed among others `getRequestURI()` which returns a `String`. And there are others, more suitable for this, like `getServletPath()`.

```
String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

if (servletPath.equals("/index")) {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
else if (servletPath.equals("/contactus")) {
    response.sendRedirect("contactus.jsp");
}

// ...
```